# Php myAdmin cannot show ő, and ű letters in any characterencoding. What can i do to fix it?

Tags: php, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a website which loads the content from database. Apparently everything's right, except for the 'ő', and 'ű' letters,
which are appearing as questionmarks. I've tried UTF-8,Latin1... non of them worked to me. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: _"I've tried UTF-8,Latin1"_ What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I've adjusted the database, the php code, and the variables of the table, to use UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the equivalent Hex code  of  such characters in order to display them You will find them in the link below:-
[URL for Hex code](http://webdesign.about.com/od/webdesign/fl/HTML-Codes-HTML-Special-Characters.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. If any of my fellow from other nation who use a weird language would like to solve their letter problems via php use this method.

```
  header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

or

```
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Paste it to the start of your code from where you send html to browser(from where you send your data to browser for printing) , so the encoding will be fine :)

Comment: <?php
 header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
# Adatbázishoz csatlakozás:

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','matestaker_grave','','db_grave') OR DIE ('Could not connect because: '.mysqli_error());

Comment: Like this? Baceuse it's still not working :S (Sorry, i'm new...)

Comment: @JustMatthew  not on your mysql connection file, use this, from where you send html to browser via php

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work either in turn it was a good idea. For days i can't manage the problem.  I' tried  -- mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8") -- Another fail.. :/

Comment: @JustMatthew where you have past it

Comment: Into the file whew my msqli_ connect located, and it affected my text, but not in the good direction.  The misery has just begun :D thx for the answers